# Can't open a ssh tunnel from my linux shell (EC2 exposing an RDS db)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, amazon-rds, ssh-tunnel

I'm struggling trying to open an ssh tunnel to access an RDS MySql instance through an EC2 bastion host. Using desktop clients (Navicat, MysqlWorkBench) with ssh tunnel set everything works as expected but when I run `ssh -i keys.pem user@ec2-instance -L 3307:rds-mysql-instance:3306 -N` in my terminal the command hangs indefinitely.

I can access my EC2 instance using `ssh -i keys.pem user@ec2-instance` and from my EC2 instance I can access the RDS database

Am I missing something in the configuration?
I also tried to open all ports on my Security Group just to be sure that it wasn't a port related issue.

Any help/idea?

Comment: add `-vv` to the end to get some info: `ssh -i keys.pem user@ec2-instance -L 3307:rds-mysql-instance:3306 -N -vv`. Also since you are using `-N` it may appear as "stuck", that's the purpose of `-N`.

Comment: Thanks, looking at the outputs I did solve the issue. It was related to my internal configuration

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

To identify the issue, more **verbose** output from `ssh` can be requested using `-v`, `-vv` or even `-vvv` flags. Thus, the command for debugging can be:

```
ssh -i keys.pem user@ec2-instance -L 3307:rds-mysql-instance:3306 -N -vv
```

The detailed output allowed to identify the issue with the connection and fix it.